# How can change background color with NSMutableAttributedString with animation during time?

Tags: uiview, core-animation, nsattributedstring

I want to change background color of text with animation. Does any way exist to set `NSAttributedStringKey.backgroundColor` with duration time?
I mean in `Hello my dear friend , how are you ?`
I want to change the background color of `friend` to yellow color with 2s (second)

Comment: You have to set yourself a timer/animation.

Answer (score 0):

**Unless** you want to change only part of the `NSAttributedString`

Did you try (Swift 3) the following?

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
     label.backgroundColor = .red
}
```

That works for the whole label...

Comment: I don't want change background color for all characters , I want to change only some characters , for instance change bgColor for char 0 to 5